# Issue in populating data in table view in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm passing an array of Any type from one view controller to my table view controller through segue method. I have three array which i'm first making its dictionary and pass that dictionary to the next view controller through segue. There i'm appending that array in another array. Then i pass that appended array to the cellForRow method to populate my data in the labels. But when print the value of the label in cell it gives nil. I'm confused why it isn't passing the value from array? No error is in a code. 
My code is this,

In my first view controller i'm appending my values in an array like this,

```
        ItemName.append(itemName!)
        ItemPrice.append(result)
        ItemDescrition.append(description)
```

Making its dictionary like this and passing it to the segue,

```
 let itemData : [String : Any] = [

         "itemName": ItemName,
         "itemPrice": ItemPrice,
         "itemDescrip": ItemDescrition

    ]

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToOrder", sender: itemData)
```

The segue method is this,

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            if segue.identifier == "GoToOrder"{
            let destination = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
                let target = destination.topViewController as! CartViewController
                target.itemData = sender as! Dictionary
            }

        }
```

In my second view controller i get the value from the dictionary and append to another array that i pass to the cellForRow method in table view,

```
 var itemData : [String : Any]! = nil
 let resultPrice = itemData["itemPrice"]
    print(resultPrice)
    let itemName = itemData["itemName"] as Any
    print(itemName)
    let itemDescrip = itemData["itemDescrip"] as Any
    nameArray.append(itemName)
    descripArray.append(itemDescrip)
    priceArray.append(resultPrice)
```

Here i'm passing that array in the table view delegate,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return nameArray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CartTableViewCell

    cell.dishTitleLbl.text = nameArray[indexPath.row] as? String
    print(cell.dishTitleLbl.text)
    cell.priceLbl.text = priceArray[indexPath.row] as? String
    print(cell.priceLbl.text)
    cell.dishDetailLbl.text = descripArray[indexPath.row] as? String
    print(cell.dishDetailLbl.text)
   // count = cell.priceLbl.text!
    print(count)
    cell.totalLbl.text = "1"
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

How can i get the values from that array in my labels in a cell?

Comment: It's highly recommended to create a custom struct as data source rather than multiple arrays. It makes things **so** much easier.

Comment: ` var itemData : [String : Any]! = nil ` is global variable or local ? don't use local variable same as global  variable name.

Comment: I agree with @vadian you should consider making a data object (doesn't have to be a `struct`) and making price and description properties of that object. Then simply create a single array of type that object. You can sort the array by any of its properties, like price. Using dictionaries with data sources in the configuration you have can get unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: var itemData : [String : Any]! = nil  is . global variable. @SidMhatre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this a little differently. First I would create an object called `Item` to store all of your items data. Then I would create a `dataSource` that you can use to call the data from anywhere in your application like so:

```
class Item : NSObject {
    var name : String
    var price : [Int] // an array of prices
    var  description : String

    init(_ name: String, _ price : [Int], _ description : String) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.description = description
    }

}

class ItemDataSource : NSObject {
    var items = [Item]()
    static let sharedInstance = ItemDataSource()
    private init() {}
}
```

Anytime you need to create a new `Item` you can do this:

```
let item = Item(“name”,[1234],”description”)
ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items.append(item)
```

Then in your `tableView` `numberOfRowsInSection` you call this:

```
ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items.count
```

You can get the info in the `cellForRowAt` like:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].name
```

Comment: Why optional properties? Please write an initializer!

Comment: I have to make a seperate class for the struct? @Jake

Comment: In my scenario the user can add as much data as he want will this scenario be good for my one?

Comment: no you can use a `struct` or a `class` and yes the `ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items` is an array very similar to what you're currently doing.

Comment: seprately i have to make a class for it? and how u are assigning the value here let item = Item()
item.name = “name” , Whats name in this? @Jake

Comment: `item.name` is what will get stored when you add it to the array. That value is `nil` in this example unless you do assign it a value which is what I did by calling `item.name = "name"` but you would replace `"name"` with the value you want.

Comment: How can i get the price from this struct seperately? @Jake

Comment: `cell.nameLabel.text = ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].price!`

Comment: Bro i want the price value seperately means if there are three price like 5,6,7 in the struct i want them out of it sepratley 5 and 6 and 7. @Jake

Comment: you make the value of price an array. like `price : [Int]`

Comment: i didn't get can u please explain? @Jake

Comment: I've edited the answer, added an initializer, and changed the `price` property

Comment: `[Int]` means an array of `Int` variables, so in your case, the price is now [5, 6, 7], just like you asked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur time that solved the issue, Big thanks:). @Jake

Comment: i want this price out of this bracket [] one by one . @Koen

Comment: Then use a subscript: price[0] is 5, price[1] is 6, etc. This is basic Array programming, maybe you want to read this first: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Comment: `for price in ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].price { print(price) } `